# How many groups of $3$ or fewer items can be made from a set of $5$ distinct items, without repetitions?

Tags: probability, combinations

How many unique sets can be made of $3$ or fewer items taken from a set of $5$ distinct items?

Comment: Define "option."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork By option, I mean possible members of a group.

Comment: Your language is inconsistent.  You write options, then you write values.

Comment: @AndrewChin Values means members of a group. Options means possible members of a group.

Comment: @MicahWindsor:  Your question makes no sense.  (I presume you're not a native English speaker.) You're telling us that you meant:  "...number of groups that can be made from five possible members of a group."  See why that makes no sense?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I am a native English speaker. I have five things. I want to know how many groups of 3 or fewer things can be made from those five things.

Comment: One way to help write the meaning of your question might be an example. Say you are given 5 people named A, B, C, D, and E. How many unique groups can be made of 3 or fewer people? The key here is staying consistent in your wording like @Andrew Chin said.

Comment: The question looked quite clear to me.

Comment: @swolo good suggestion

Comment: @MicahWindsor:  So you have a set $\{ A, B, C, D, E \}$ and want to know how many "groups" can be made from those "things" if each group must contain $1$, $2$ or $3$ elements.  So is $\{ \{ A, B, C\}, \{D \}, \{E \}\}$ different from $\{ \{ D \}, \{ C, B, A \}, \{E \}\}$??  Please use standard mathematical terminology, otherwise we'll all waste even more time.

Comment: Oh my goodness... On top of very confusing, non-standard terminology, now the OP changes the question to allow groups of size (cardinality) $0$.  I'm done here.  Over and out.

Comment: In jargon:  are we talking about "unique sets of subsets" or "unique subsets"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Someone understood. You were the one who deleted the part of my question that said I'm new to this area. If you can't answer, don't bother.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork that sounds more like "*groupings*" to me... but yes... using the standard terminology should clear this all up.  It may be best to phrase this in terms of sets and subsets... Given a set with $n$ distinct elements, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of that set of size $k$.  Add over all possible sizes if you are interested in the count of subsets in a particular range of sizes...

Comment: @AndrewChin I have no idea lol. See accepted answer.

Comment: If you were instead asking about the number of *groupings*, or using proper language, *partitions* of the set... that would be the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).  If you add the restriction on the size or number of parts, then that changes it further.  There are dozens of other ways to slightly alter the flavor of the problem in order to get yet another different answer, but those are the two interpretations that came to mind first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the meaning of your question, you have 5 unique values and you must find how many total groups of 3 or fewer values you can make. This can be the sum of each group size you have.

For the amount of groups of 1, you have $5 \choose 1$

For the amount of groups of 2, you have $5 \choose 2$

And for the amount of groups of 3, you have $5 \choose 3$

Additionally, you have the amount for a group of 0, which is $5 \choose 0$$=1$

Taking the sum of these will give you your answer.

Comment: You forgot about the group of size $0$.

Comment: True, thank you @AndrewChin I will add that to my answer.

Comment: Perfect, you understood correctly! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^3 {5 \choose k} = 25$

Comment: Don't forget $k=0$.

Comment: The OP specifically said 1, 2 or 3, but evidently has been changed since.